# NodeJs not taking post requests

Tags: node.js

This is a simple app that takes a post request and saves mail id in it.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index',
  { title : 'Home' }
  )
});

app.post(
        '/mail/',
        function(req,res){
            Mail.addMail(

                req.body.mailid,
                function(err,mail){
                    if((mail) &&(!err)){
                        res.send(200);
                    }
                    else{
                        res.send(401,err);
                    }
                }

                );
        }
        );


app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

When I try to ping it via python:

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/mail/')
```

The server doesnt' respond at all. Not even a post request gets registered. The get request works fine, though. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your handler doesn't run at all? If you put a `console.log` above `Mail.addMail` it doesn't print anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Are you using express.js ?

Comment: @Hick Assuming you are using express, there is no problem with the code you have posted. It must be an issue with another portion of the code.

Comment: have you tried the same without `Mail.addMail`function ? I suspect it is not returning any response.

Answer (score 1):

I think that node.js routes should be defined without the trailing slash - you could try that.

Apart from that it looks fine to me..

Comment: @Hick Have you removed trailing slash from `app.post` as well as `requests.post`?